# Result for a projection's list with a hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection

I'm using a criteria with projections to extract 2 columns from my database. However, I would like a result as 2 lists of simple elements instead of 1 list of elements.

My criteria :

final DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Valeur.class, "value")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("value.parametre.id", parameterId))
        (... more restrictions ...)
    criteria.setProjection( Projections.distinct( Projections.projectionList()
                .add( Projections.property( "value.valeurVal" ) )
                .add( Projections.property( "measure.mesureDate" ) ) ) );

```
    criteria.addOrder( Order.asc("measure.mesureDate") );

final List<Data> result =  (List<Data>)  criteria.getExecutableCriteria(_sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).list();
```

My Data object :

```
private double _value;
@NotNull
private Date _date;
```

In this case, I have a list of Data, but I want to have TWO lists : one of double and the other of Date. Is this possible ? Any idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help.
vanessa

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the return list, you can output it manually into two lists:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
results = criteria.list();
if(results != null) {
    for (Object[] row : results) {
        stringList.add((String)row[0]);
        integerList.add((Integer)row[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I'm still wondering if it's possible to do this directly with Hibernate, because I'm working with a lot of data (nearly 50 000 lines for each columns) and I would prefer to avoid a loop "for".

Thanks for your help.
vanessa

Comment: Based on the JavaDoc (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#setResultTransformer(org.hibernate.transform.ResultTransformer)), it appears that you can only set one `ResultTransformer` on a given Criteria query, so it appears the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will use your solution. Have a good day. vanessa